# Error Trying Open a File From a Directory

Tags: c#

I am trying to open a file, but I received:

> The process cannot access the file 'X:\SubGraph\Prozess A.1.1.wkd'
>   because it is being used by another process.

Can anyone help?

```
string activeDirectory = @"X:\SubGraph\";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(activeDirectory);
foreach (string fileName in files){
    FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: Sounds stupid but have you made sure the file is not being used by another process? You could try a reboot so that you know that there should be no other processes unless they are system processes that have a lock on that file.

Comment: How could i know which Process are using this File

Comment: Download [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to open it by giving FileShare.Read

```
FileStream s2 = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

> **Take from MSDN for FileShare.Read** Allows subsequent opening of
>   the file for reading. If this flag is not specified, any request to
>   open the file for reading (by this process or another process) will
>   fail until the file is closed. However, even if this flag is
>   specified, additional permissions might still be needed to access the
>   file.

Comment: it doesnt help, somtimes it worked sometimes not